# Challenging function, macro and or script to assign a value (1-6) dynamically and equally to a specific row range in a column

Tags: function, google-apps-script

I have made an example sheet to help show what I have failed to do for a couple of weeks now. You are welcome and encouraged to make edits if you believe you can help solve this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uPBaqQ_qbmSiPgW2EM3As-GreAvAurN4edXXwIWrimI/edit?usp=sharing

I have a sheet "YT Filtered" that is displaying rows of data filtered from another sheet.
There are 6 teams who then divide the rows and complete work for them.
Each team has a separate sheet that uses =IMPORTRANGE and looks for their number in. Col (L).

It would be very useful if there was a way to assign numbers to Col (L), "Team Number (1-6)" as the filtered data changes (on edit) or with the click of a button with a script assigned to it.

As the number of rows can change, it would need to count the rows, divide them by 6 (for the 6 teams), and then assign a number to each row, using each number as equally as possible. The numbers don't have to be in order.

Where I am struggling is I can't use a volatile function like =RANDBETWEEN or =RAND because the constant change and the work are mixed all of the time.

I've tried for countless hours over two weeks to solve this through forums, friends, and videos. I am still learning and this is beyond me. I would be very grateful to anyone who can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a formula in the "YT Filtered" tab, cell L2 and it seems to be working as you need.

The formula used is this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A), "", MOD(ROUNDUP((ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1)/CEILING(COUNTA(A2:A)/6,1),0),6)+1))
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work. I am very excited to learn and get to a point where I can handle more complex functions like you.